# Is there a difference between 1D Mean Shift and KDE for clustering 1 d data?

Tags: clustering, density-estimation, nonparametric-density, mean-shift

I need to cluster (or group) large one dimensional data sets into a set of fixed bins. I started out using K-means, but I want to look into other approaches. 
Two that I have found are Mean Shift and KDE, but when I actually looked into the details, they were both Parzen window non parametric estimators.

Is there a difference between the two?

Also does DBSCAN do the same thing as well?

Answer (score 5):

Mean shift essentially tries to appproximate the *local maxima* of the KDE using a heuristic search.

Full KDE can do much more than that.

DBSCAN looks for connected components. It uses a binary density model (i.e. dense enough, or noise).